# Как реализовать адаптивность в element.io?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

К примеру на десктопе структура блока:

```
<el-row>
  <el-col :span="12"></el-col>
  <el-col :span="12"></el-col>
</el-row>,
```

А на мобильном должно быть:

```
<el-row>
  <el-col :span="24"></el-col>
</el-row>,
```

Как делать мобильную верстку, не могу нагуглить примеры сайтов адаптивных на element.io?

Comment: все есть в документации, [смотрите Responsive Layout](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/layout#responsive-layout). Внизу страницы параметры Col Attributes

Comment: @MrFylypenko да, я смотрел эту документацию, но проблема в другом, как и описал в посте. У меня на десктопе в 1 ряду должно быть 2 колонки, а на мобильном должна быть одна колонка, брекпоинты тут не помогут, так как они задают ширину этой колонки, но не решают моей проблемы, мне нужно на мобильном оставить 1 колонку, а на десктопе 2; Т.е структура должна быть другой

Comment: По ссылке что привел, там есть раздел `Utility classes for hiding elements` , можете указать нужный параметр для скрытия элемента при определенной ширине экрана, в итоге будет видно только один `el-col`